# sqlDeveloper no encuentra Java Runtime Environment

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

tengo un problema con el cliente de BD, sqlDeveloper y lo que pasa es que me genera un error de ejecución:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y me puedan ayudar, las variables de entorno ya están configuradas que previamente instale! y me siguio generando ese error!

Quedo al pendiente, de antemano les mando un cordial saludo.

Comment: ¿sqlDeveloper por si acaso es de 64 bits?

Answer (score 0):

Es necesario editar el **sqldeveloper.conf**, debe estar en **DIRECTORIO DE INSTALACION\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf**.

Busca la clave **SetJavaHome** y completa con la dirección de instalación del java

[image: jdk dir]

Comment: Hola de nuevo! El detalle que es portable, es decir, es un cliente que nos pasaron en el trabajo para poder manipular la bd, la opcion que me proporcionaste no viene ningun archivo de configuración. ya intente con desinstalar el jdk y todo lo relacionado con java y sin exito! Sigue sin encontrar la ruta.

Comment: Yo tuve el mismo problema y también fue potable, dentro de la carpeta sqldeveloper/bin debe estar ubicado el archivo de configuración.

Comment: Hola a todos, buenos dias, busque esa ubicación y no estaba, sqldeveloper/bin y no la tiene, pero pues ya opte por mas opciones e instale otro cliente que se llama squirrel y ya pude solucionar mi problema con esto, gracias a todos por responder mi pregunta, saludos y buena vibra